# How can I find two field from two different models in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

The first model is called --> Post

The second model is called --> User

find ({fieldA = true in Post} and find ({fieldB = true in User}) then send the result as JSON File.

Comment: What do you expect your "result" to be?  A `Post`, a `User`, or something else?

Comment: The result will be list of posts.

Comment: Can you describe how the `Post`s are related to the `User`?  And are you doing this directly in Mongo or are you able to do some JavaScript as well?

Comment: inside the Post, There is a field I want to target and in the User model I need to check another filed. Thus, both fields need to be true in order to find the right posts to render.

Comment: But how does the `User` model interact with the `Post` model?  Why would a `Post` care about a field on `User` being true?  How would that affect which `Post`s you return?

Comment: router.get("/schooltime/:school", requireLogin, (req, res) => {

  // Return Posts when schoolFeed--> true && school --> value that is sent from frontend
  Post.find({schoolFeed: true }) 
    .populate("postedBy", "_id name") 
    .then((posts) => {
      res.json({ posts: posts });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});                                                                                                                                               this is the code for that route

Comment: ^^ That would be a great thing to add to your question instead of in the comments

Comment: I was not able to add it.

Comment: do you want all posts those are related to a specific user?

Comment: yes, I need something like this                                                                                                                Post.find({schoolFeed: true }) && User.find({school: req.body.school})                                           school will be sent from the frontend

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all posts those are belongs to a specific user and also want to add check for posts records.

We can use aggregate function in order to get relational data.

Get all user those are in requested school:

```js
{
   $match: {
      school: req.body.school 
   }
}
```

Using lookup can get user's posts with extra check

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "posts",
        let: {
            userId: "$_id"
        },
        pipeline: [
          { $match: {
               $expr: { $and: [
                  { $eq: [ "$schoolFeed", true ] },
                  { $eq: [ "$postedBy", "$$userId" ] }
              ] }
          } }
        ],
        as: "posts"
    }
}
```

And the final query is:

```
User.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        school: "test" 
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "posts",
        let: {
            userId: "$_id"
        },
        pipeline: [
          { $match: {
               $expr: { $and: [
                  { $eq: [ "$schoolFeed", true ] },
                  { $eq: [ "$postedBy", "$$userId" ] }
              ] }
          } }
        ],
        as: "posts"
    }
}
])
```